# Twilio Machine Detection AnsweredBy field returns 'None'

Tags: python, twilio, twilio-api

I'm developing a Twilio app that leverages the Machine Detection features. I make a request using the Twilio python client as follows:

```
import twilio
twilio_client = Client(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN)

call = twilio_client.calls.create(
        to=number,
        from_=TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER,
        url=EXTERNAL_URL + '/call',
        status_callback=EXTERNAL_URL + '/call_status',
        status_callback_event=["initiated", "ringing", "answered",
                               "completed", "no-answer", "busy",
                               "failed", "canceled", "queued"],
        machine_detection='Enable',
        machine_detection_timeout=20,
    )
```

but when I try to access the `call.answered_by` field I discover that the value is `None`. I also get back `None` when I use the call status API to fetch the call status 10 seconds later:

```
call = twilio_client.calls(sid).fetch()
```

Also in my my webhook that I register at `EXTERNAL_URL + '/call_status' to get notifications I don't get an 'AnsweredBy' field. I've also made sure I enabled the feature in the Twilio web console. What else I am missing?

Comment: here are the links to the documentation btw: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/answering-machine-detection

Comment: Which country are you calling to?

Comment: I'm calling the US.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45740616/retrieved-answered-by-response-as-null

Comment: I ran your code and it works fine. I'm not sure why you mention `call.answered_by` because the field name is `AnsweredBy` and is passed as parameter (POST request) to the webhook for `EXTERNAL_URL + '/call'` and you won't find it in `EXTERNAL_URL + /call_status`.

Comment: Thanks Alex. Looks like `AnsweredBy` only appears in the `/call` call back request and doesn't get populated in the either API endpoints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Thanks to Andy and Alex in the comments, I think they actually do cover everything.

The key here is that the `AnsweredBy` field will be sent as part of the webhook to the URL you set as the `url` parameter in the API request. In this case, that is the URL `EXTERNAL_URL + '/call'`.

The `AnsweredBy` field should eventually appear in the REST API for the call resource itself, but the way to use it is via the webhook.

Let me know if this helps at all.